# Why doesn't directive work if I put name as an attribute rather than a tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the example from the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), a directive can be used by putting its name as an attribute in a `<div>`. The example given is

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-customer></div>
</div>
```

with the js looking like

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
    };
  });
```

However, in a similar example, over here, if I change the `html` code from `<tree>` to `<div tree>`, the code no longer works.

Why not?

The code from JS Fiddle:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="TreeCtrl">
        <tree family="treeFamily">
            <p>{{ family.name }}</p>
        </tree>
    </div>
</div>


var module = angular.module('myapp', []);

module.controller("TreeCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.treeFamily = {
        name : "Parent",
        children: [{
            name : "Child1",
            children: [{
                name : "Grandchild1",
                children: []
            },{
                name : "Grandchild2",
                children: []
            },{
                name : "Grandchild3",
                children: []
            }]
        }, {
            name: "Child2",
            children: []
        }]
    };
});

module.directive("tree", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        scope: {family: '='},
            template:       
            '<ul>' + 
                '<li ng-transclude></li>' +
                '<li ng-repeat="child in family.children">' +
                    '<tree family="child">{{family.name}}</tree>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttr, transclude) {
            var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
            var compiledContents;
            return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
                if(!compiledContents) {
                    compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude);
                }
                compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                         iElement.append(clone); 
                });
            };
        }
    };
});

tree {
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restrict option is used to specify how a directive can be invoked on the page. There are four different ways to invoke a directive, so there are four valid options for restrict:

```
'A' - attribute - <span ng-sparkline></span>
'E' - element - <ng-sparkline></ng-sparkline>
'C' - class - <span class="ng-sparkline"></span>
'M' - comment - <!-- directive: ng-sparkline -->
```

In your case its not working because it is defined as restrict 'E' - element.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `restrict` option in the directive.

Here it is set to `e` which means to match only the element name.

More https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive